# Map layer 'ajt' fails to load

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

After following the tutorial from [Switch2OSM](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-20-04-lts/) I ran into the following error after running this command: **renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf** and launching the server through the web browser using this address: **http://localhost/hot/0/0/0.png**

```
renderd[64331]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': Could not create datasource for type: 'postgis' (no datasource plugin directories have been successfully registered)  encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 803 of '/home/user/src/openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml'
renderd[64331]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
renderd[64331]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[64331]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(0), x(0), y(0), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[64331]: Received request for map layer 'ajt' which failed to load
renderd[64331]: DEBUG: Sending render cmd(4 ajt 0/0/0) with protocol version 2 to fd 7
renderd[64331]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
```

After doing some research I haven't found anything useful to solve this problem.